# Installing Ubuntu from USB drive

Tags: 13.04, usb, live-usb

I used both programs from http://pendrivelinux.com.

Whenever I boot from USB and choose Install to Hard Drive, it stucks at:

```
nouveau [ VBIOS][0000:01:00.0] checking PRAMIN for image
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to the forum! I really want to help you, but you have to give some more informations: What do you mean when you say: "I used both programs"? And which option did you select, trying to install Ubuntu: Erase disk and install Ubuntu alone, or try to install Ubuntu alongside an other operative system? Good luck with linux, hope it will a bit easyier when you get ahed with this problem!

Comment: "YUMI – Your Universal Multiboot Installer" and
"Universal USB Installer – Easy as 1 2 3"...
Those are 2 programs (they are practically same I guess), chose option to format disk to FAT32 before starting the process each time I tried. Disk was completely empty before puting Ubuntu in it. @IndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is a missing file on your USB.
I would recommend using Unetbootin to burn the image
to your USB and use that to install Ubuntu.
I have had errors like your in the past using pendrivelinux
but Unetbootin has always created good images.

Comment: Yes I tried but when I choose, "Default" or "Install Ubuntu" or the other option (which is about trying Ubuntu without installing it), nothing happens. Just a blinking underscore.

Comment: Hmmm, okay. A blinking underscore may well be caused by data not being read fast enough from your flash drive. Also, there is a likelyhood that data is stil missing and a search is going on. I want to suggest to  you to fully erase the flash drive then write ubuntu to it again and try to instal it one more time. This will eliminate any errors from misreads.  I want to ask you what speed are your USB ports? and what speed is your flash drive?  Another thought is please check your hard drive to make sure it's properly recognized by your bios on the motherboard. Check that it has good connections

Comment: Please also let me know what size is your flash drive? And check in your computers bios to see if it is being properly recognized as a usb flash drive.

Comment: Well I fixed the problem now, apparently problem was not related to programs I use. I found out that in my laptop I have to change graphic option from "Switchable" to "Integrated". Now I succesfully installed it. I have to use integrated graphics to choose ubuntu at the start now, which is another problem for me. But thats another story, thank you a lot for advices.